# Using the output of intermediate layers in a loss function in TF2

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to replicate the training of OpenPose in Tensorflow 2 as part of my TF2 learning, but to be able to do this I need to use the output of the S, L intermediate layers in my loss function.

I've tried using the functional API but I can't seem to get the output from the S/L layers to be able to use them in a loss function as required. I can see how this might be possible with subclassing but that would add complexity and not as ideal for debugging. Debugging and ease of use would probably be a massive plus at this stage in my learnings.

Is there any way I can do this type of model with the functional API or sequential model?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, both functional and sequential keras models support this. You can always pass a `dict` containing the layer names as keys and loss functions as values. Here is a code demonstrating this.

If you want to construct a model from scratch, you can just add the layer as one of the model's outputs.

```
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.keras.Input([128, 128, 3], name='image')
conv_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, 1, name='conv_1')(img)
conv_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, 1, name='conv_2')(conv_1)
conv_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, 1, name='conv_3')(conv_2)
conv_4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, 1, name='conv_4')(conv_3)
conv_5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, 1, name='conv_5')(conv_4)
avg_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool2D(name='avg_pool')(conv_5)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(avg_pool)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[img], outputs=[output, conv_5])
print(model.outputs)
```

output:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'dense/Sigmoid:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'conv_5/BiasAdd:0' shape=(None, 118, 118, 16) dtype=float32>]
```

But incase you are working with a model that is already constructed you can use the `model.get_layer` method to access a layer and create a new model:

```
intermediate_layer = model.get_layer('avg_pool').output
new_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.outputs + [intermediate_layer])
print(new_model.outputs)
```

output:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'dense/Sigmoid:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'conv_5/BiasAdd:0' shape=(None, 118, 118, 16) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Tensor 'avg_pool/Mean:0' shape=(None, 16) dtype=float32>]
```

And then compiling your model and specifying a separate loss for each of the model's outputs. These losses can be strings if they are the default losses that Keras provides, or these can be callables that implement your loss function.

```
new_model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss={
                  'dense': 'binary_crossentropy',
                  'conv_5': 'mse',
                  'avg_pool': 'mae'
              })
```

Some dummy data and labels

```
images = tf.random.normal([100, 128, 128, 3])
conv_3_labels = tf.random.normal([100, 118, 118, 16])
avg_pool_labels =  tf.random.normal([100, 16])
class_labels = tf.random.uniform([100], 0, 2, tf.float32)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (images, (class_labels, conv_3_labels, avg_pool_labels))
)
dataset = dataset.batch(4, drop_remainder=True)
```

Training

```
new_model.fit(dataset)
```

output:

```
25/25 [==============================] - 2s 79ms/step - loss: 2.4339
- dense_loss: 0.3904 - conv_5_loss: 1.2367 - avg_pool_loss: 0.8068
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer @Srihari. The model is being built by me so I could use either method. Is there much overhead or performance drawbacks to using the multiple model/new_model.outputs apporach or is it all generated into a single graph anyway? The initial way seems more simple, but then I'd have to return 7 layer outputs which seems a little messy in one outputs=[]. Thanks again!